# Calling loadView for UITableViewController subclass

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview, loadview

I make an instance of a subclass of UITableViewController without a xib.  I am not going to be using a xib file.  I build the data in the `-(id)init` routine.  I create the data for the table in the `-(id)init` function, and use the methods of the UITableViewDataSource and UITableViewDelegate protocols to display and select the data.  I load the UITableViewController subclass into a UINavigationController using the `[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController: myTVC];`  All of this succeeds IF I do not define the loadView method for the class. If I make a blank loadView method an empty UIView is put on the screen.

My Question: How do I write the correct loadView function for a simple subclass of UITableViewController?

Answer (score 3):

One should never call through to `[super loadView]` per Apple's documentation: 
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/loadView

The correct way to handle this is to simply instantiate a view and set it to self.view, and in this case self.tableView as well:

```
- (void)loadView {
    UITableView* tableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero style:UITableViewStylePlain];
    tableView.delegate = self;
    tableView.dataSource = self;

    self.view = tableView;
    self.tableView = tableView;
}
```